# Request Tracker 4.x on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apache2

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 server installed on my machine. I am trying to install request-tracker4. Here's what I have done so far :

1. Installed request-tracker via "`sudo apt-get install request-tracker4`"
2. I then tried configuring RT_SiteConfig.pm in `/etc/request-tracker4` but then ran into problems in populating the MySQL database.
3. I then did `sudo dpkg-reconfigure request-tracker4`

   - It solved my problems of not being able to populate / setup mysql etc.
   - Now, I am trying to setup rt under `www.mydomain.com/rt`

I have read various how-to's and bestpractical's own guides but I am not very much a expert in Apache configurations so stuck.

My Current Ubuntu 12.04 server setup:

Apache2, Fastcgi installed (checked in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`
Web Server document root is default `/var/www/`
Web user `www-data`

Question is :

1. Where and What shall I put in Apache configuration to start using RT via the web-interface ?

I have seen two files in `/etc/request-tracker4/`

`apache2-fastcgi.conf` and `apache2-fcgid.conf`
I even tried making a `ln -s apache2-fastcgi.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d` but when I tried opening that file in root while in the conf.d directory it said `too many levels`.

Any request tracker experts on Ubuntu ?:-)

Your help will be very useful and appreciated.

Thanks

Please let me know if you need further info !

Answer (score 1):

As far as the Apache configuration goes, you should only need to follow [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Request%20Tracker) if you have a vanilla Apache2 installation. I wouldn't recommend using `fastcgi` to get the base installation running. You also shouldn't need to touch the RT_SiteConfig.pm Perl module.

Additionally, you will need to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install rt4-apache2 rt4-clients rt4-db-mysql request-tracker4 rt4-extension-assettracker fetchmail
```

As far as the Apache2 config goes, the following should get you started:

Run the command:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Append the following at the bottom of the file on a new line:

```
ServerName tickets
```

Save the file & run the command:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Find the last line `<?/VirtualHost>` and paste in the following two lines just above it:

```
Include /etc/request-tracker3.8/apache2-modperl2.conf
RedirectMatch ^/$ /rt
```

Save the file & run the command:

```
a2enmod rewrite; service apache2 restart
```

Again, these guidelines were taken from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Request%20Tracker) and have successfully worked for me on about five production deployments.

Also, take a look at my more detailed installation answer on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/249153/106495).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `Include /etc/request-tracker4/apache2-fastcgi.conf` in your virtual host config file, for instance in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`.